# AJAX not working properly in Firefox

Tags: javascript, ajax, firefox

I'm using Firefox 20.0.1 and Apache. I have some AJAX calls to retrieve an HTML document from the server. The strange thing is that in one function an AJAX call works fine, but in another function to get a different document it doesn't work. Also, it does work in Chrome.

Any ideas on what this could be? The code is as follows:

```
loc = "Temp\folder1\folder2\title.html";
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.open("POST", loc, false);
req.send();
alert(req.responseText); // Displays "object not found" error.
```

**Background Information:**
I am writing an EPUB reader. The EPUB file is stored on the server and extracted using PHP. I want to get (for example) chapter 1's content, which is stored in an HTML document in the extracted location.

**Solution**
The problem was the Firefox has issues with backslashes in URLs.
I simply replaced all backslashes with forward slashes before sending the request.

Comment: Any reason you're using `false` to make it synchronous? Since it's a POST request, you might want to use `req.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");` right before the `req.send();`. Are you sure that URL is exists?

Comment: No real reason for making it synchronous; may change it when it works. I added the setRequestHeader and it still doesn't work. Yes, I'm 100% sure the URL exists (it works in Chrome).

Comment: So what is shown if you do `alert(req.status);` right before your other `alert`?

Comment: That means the page isn't found :)

Comment: If this is in an external Javascript file, I don't think the navigation (like "\Temp\folder\........" starts from the HTML file - it starts from the Javascript file. You might want to use an absolute URL, starting with "/" or "\"

Comment: You could look at your browser's console to see what the actual URL ends up being evaluated as, to figure out what the problem is. You can also use your browser's console to see a lot more about the request/response that could've helped figure this out sooner

Comment: It works with Chrome though. From looking at the console it appears as though Firefox doesn't like having \s in the URL

Comment: I know, it's weird it's working differently in browsers. And I didn't even think of that! Yeah, why are you using "\" instead of "/"?

Comment: The "\"s were obtained from using the RecursiveDirectoryIterator and RecursiveIteratorIterator to search for a file's path. Thanks for the help :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "object not found" text is an alias for an HTTP 404 error in some web servers. If you run `alert(req.status);` after your `req.send();`, it can provide insight into what may be the problem. In your case, it is in fact showing a 404 error, and can be traced back to the URL having `\` characters in it.